# Angular scope from ng-controller on custom directive that uses transclusion

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-transclude

I'm pretty new to Angular still, so I apologize if this is a silly question...  I have a custom directive that uses transclusion, and I'm trying to understand why data binding works if I assign an ng-controller to a parent element, but not when I assign the controller directly onto it:

Code:

```
angular.module('HelloWorld', [])

.controller('HelloController', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'you'
})

.directive('hello', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<ng-transclude />'
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<!-- why does this one work? -->
<div ng-controller="HelloController">
  <hello>Hi there, {{name}}!</hello>
</div>

<!-- but not this one? -->
<hello ng-controller="HelloController">
  <p> Hi there, {{name}}!</p>
</hello>
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/ICztHcKU4W2EgFmy8OqQ?p=preview

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A directive is defined as a function that returns an object (with template, bindings, controller and other properties) that is compiled into an element.

Whatever attribute you put inside your  element is passed to the directive bindings (or isolated scope), it is not interpreted.

You could technically pass the controller as an attribute to your directive but it doesn't look like good practice since directives have a controller property.

For example this would work: https://plnkr.co/edit/WknbSDI4HlQyp2vQIkbR?p=preview

```
angular.module('HelloWorld', [])

.controller('HelloController', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'you'
})

    .directive('hello', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          ngController: '&'
        },
        transclude: true,
        template: '<ng-transclude />',
        controller: ngController
      };
    });
```

But you see you could use

```
controller: function() {}
```

directly inside the directive which would make it more independent.

Comment: I see... thanks.  The original reason I started down this path was because I was using Angular Material's md-button directive ( https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdButton ) and trying to assign an ng-controller to one and data bind in a title for it -- but the title never showed up until I moved the controller up a level.  Is that kind of use case just generally not expected/recommended I guess?

Comment: A controller controls an HTML element. A directive (with restrict E) before compilation is not an HTML element. It's not recommended to pass a controller as an attribute of a directive because you will have code all over the place.

Comment: @chinabuffet If you need a directive to have its own controller (similar to a component) and make it more standalone and reusable, just use the controller property.